# How to pause TextToSpeech along with the activity?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-activity

While developing TextToSpeech got a doubt that if we pause the activity how can we pause the TextToSpeeh along with the activity...If we resume the activity the text to speech will start where it has stopped previously...

How can we achieve this?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TTS SDK doesn't have any pause functionality that I know of. But you could use `synthesizeToFile()` to create an audio file that contains the TTS output. Then, you would use a MediaPlayer object to play, pause, and stop playing the file. Depending on how long the text string is, it might take a little longer for audio to be produced because the `synthesizeToFile()` function would have to complete the entire file before you could play it, but this delay should be acceptable for most applications.